# SQL turn a dynamic number of rows into columns with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I have a large table with up to 90 rows and 40 columns. For sake of SSRS reporting this data needs to be converted into one column so that it can be displayed as a single page report. I will not use all rows but a good 50 are applicable to the reporting dataset.

I've looked around for several solutions but they often hinge on a 3 column dataset and it does not work because of the number of columns & rows I need to rotate.

The question is, is it possible? And if so, what would be the best approach?

Pivot might be a solution but I was wondering if there is a faster way to move all 2nd, 3rd etc rows to the top row and add the identifier in front of the columnName from the row being moved up?

Sample table:

```
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |ActID | MList | List | Seg | Amt1  | Amt2 | Amt3 | Amt4 | Date1  | Date2  | Char1  |... Char30 |
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |ABCD  |    1  |   1  | AA  | 20.00 | 5.00 | 0    | 0    | 1/2/19 | 2/5/19 | Null   |    Text1  |                            
        |ABCD  |    1  |   2  | AB  | 0     | 0    | 0    | 0    | Null   | Null   | Null   |    Null   |      
        |ABCD  |    1  |   3  | AC  | 35.00 | 24.00| 33.00| 0    | Null   | Null   | Text3  |    Text4  |                                 
        |ABCD  |    2  |   1  | AA  | 0     | 0    | 0    | 0    | 5/5/17 | 3/5/12 | Text19 |    Text30 |              
        |ABCD  |    2  |   2  | AB  | 25.00 | 99.00| 18.00| 5.00 | 2/2/14 | 3/3/19 | Null   |    Null   |                                         
        |FGHA  |    1  |   1  | AA  | 0     | 0    | 0    | 0    | Null   | Null   | Text22 |    Null   |                            
        |FGHA  |    1  |   2  | AB  | 0     | 0    | 0    | 0    | 1/1/20 | 1/1/20 | Null   |    Text5  |                            
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I'm attempting to do is use the first two columns as identifiers and then conflate all amount/character/date field columns by using List+Seg fields as helpful markings.

So the end result would be something like:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|ActID | MList | 1AAAmt1 | 1AAAmt2 | 1AAAmt3 | 1AAAmt4 |1AADate1 |1AADate2 | 1AAChar1 |...1AAChar30 | 2ABAmt1 | 2ABAmt2 | 2ABAmt3 | 2ABAmt4 | 2ABDate1 |2ABDate2 | 2ABChar1 |...2ABChar30 | ...etc |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|ABCD  |   1   | 20.00   | 5.00    | 0       | 0       | 1/2/19  | 2/5/19  | Null     |     Text1   | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       | Null     | Null    | Null     | Null        | ...etc |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

First time asking a question, I normally browse but found nothing that quite resolves my issue of sheer row/column numbers and the dynamics of it.  Hope this illustrates the problem well.

This is using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Pivoting is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS allows you to create Row and Column groups to dynamically pivot your data in a matrix. In this example you would have a Row group on ActID and a Column group on List. The column group would encompass those ~37 columns and repeat them all for each List number in the dataset.

If you query the `Char` fields in rows instead of columns, you could have a variable number of them and use that as a nested column group in the report.

In general, I've found that it's best to query data into rows whenever possible and let the report grouping do the heavy lifting.